# Python Sqlite3 - query varchar as unicode

Tags: sqlite, unicode, encoding, sqlite3-python

I have a database which can have any characters for username ( chinese etc ) it is created using sqlite3 C api ( i don't know the details not good in C ) - and the field for name has `VARCHAR` type. I have a question, how i can query get the varchar fields in unicode?

Currently i simply do:

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("protasovo.db")

cur = con.cursor()
res = cur.execute("SELECT name,tx FROM clients")

for index,obj in enumerate(res.fetchall()):
    print(obj[0])
```

For chinese names i get garbage in console... How i can get this name as unicode? So each character would be encoded with 2 bytes